# No response when using required HTTP Referer and User-agent

Tags: curl, http-headers, user-agent, http-referer, lynx

Please can someone see what is wrong in my curl request. Thanks in advance

***Requirements:***

1. In order to access the instructions for submitting your resume, you must GET the "/anvato-resumes/instructions.txt" resource from this web service:
   https://s3.amazonaws.com
2. You must make it appear as if you're sending the GET request by following a link to the resource from http://www.anvato.com using a Lynx web browser. Otherwise, the web service will give you an Access Denied error.

***Solution:***

```
curl -X GET --header "Referer: www.anvato.com" --header "User-Agent: Lynx/2.8.8dev.3 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1" https://s3.amazonaws.com/anvato-resumes/instructions.txt
```

***Response:***

(XML) Access denied

Comment: Try use the `--cookie` option.

Comment: `--cookie` did not work :(
`curl -X GET --header "Referer: www.anvato.com" --header "User-Agent: Lynx/2.8.8dev.3 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1" --cookie 'test.txt' https://s3.amazonaws.com/anvato-resumes/instructions.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below works !

```
curl  -A "Lynx/2.8.8dev.3 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1" -e "http://www.anvato.com"  -X GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/anvato-resumes/instructions.txt
```